# Possibility of use of SSE for mentioned logic

Tags: c, sse

I am planning to do SSE coding for the below logic

```
int num[10]= {0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255};
for (int i =0;i<9;i++){    
         num[i+1]=num[i]<<1;    
}
```

Whether It is possible to do the SSE implementation for the above logic as num[i+1] is depend on num[i]

(am planning to use __m128i type of registers)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you write out of the bounds of the array in the last iteration of the for loop

Comment: Your original code crashes (access beyond the edge of the array). 
Modified code:

    int num[11]= {0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255};
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {    
        num[i + 1] = num[i] << 1;    
        std::cout << num[i + 1] << std::endl;
    }
Print 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.

Comment: Thanks Alter and Ermlg for this access beyond the edge of the array condition check.I have updated my question with your suggestions .This is my dummy code and I want to write the SSE for the above code ..So I am waiting for somebody to answer interns of SSE

Comment: did you try anything yourself? also a length of 10 bytes is a strange length for trying to do SSE operations...

Comment: Actually, the iterations are _not_ interdependent. The induction variable is `i`, and the loop can be parallelized by shifting in each iteration `num[0]` left by `i` bits, producing `num[i] = num[0] << i;`. Thus, your friend here is the SSE instruction `pslld` with three different shift controls (`{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11}`); This will do your job.

Comment: What @IwillnotexistIdonotexist said. And since your num[0] is zero your program just sets all elements of num[] to zero. Also: if you are not calculating anything else then your algorithm will likely be limited by your FSB bandwidth anyways and SSE would not make things any faster.

Comment: Your code does not make much sense, as it doesn't do anything useful or meaningful - you need to provide real, tested scalar code that actually implements something useful before anyone can give good advice as to SIMD optimisation.

Comment: @PaulR ,I can not write complete code here but what ever I posted is the dummy code as like my application .This is a part of my code where I am checking the objectness in a frame/image .

Comment: @PaulR ,Please let me know that whether I can implement the SSE logic for the above code and how .as I am thinking the num[i+1] is depend on num[i] ,so in a dilemma to use SSE ...

Comment: Your dummy code is not much help - you need to provide code which at least closely represents what you are trying to achieve. In particular you need to specify (a) the *size of the data set* (generating 10 ints is obviously not representative of something that you would need to optimise) and (b) *exactly what processing operations are being performed* (your example just fills all 10 array values with 0, so it might as well just be a call to `memset`).

Comment: ok..give me some time for this I will try to post the dummy code ..

Answer (score -1):

SSE operations are performed independently for each element of vector. If there is a dependency between them, then we have sequential algorithm which can not effectively be executed with using SIMD CPU instructions.

Example:

```
const int first = 0;//1;
int num[10]= {first,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255};
for (int i = 0 ; i < 9; i++)
{    
    num[i + 1] = num[i] << 1;    
    std::cout << num[i + 1] << " ";
}
```

prints 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (first = 0);
prints 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 (first = 1).
All elements in resultant array depends from first.

There is a SSE implementation, but I think that it not has any practical sense:

```
const int first = 1;
int num[10]= {first, 255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255};
int i = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < 4; i++)
    num[i + 1] = num[i] << 1; 
for (; i < 8; i += 4)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(num + i - 4 + 1));
    v = _mm_slli_epi32(v, 4);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)(num + i + 1), v);
}
for (; i < 9; ++i)
    num[i + 1] = num[i] << 1;
```

Comment: I want to know that for above logic SSE implementation is possible ??If yes the how and If no then WHY !!!

Comment: @Ashwin, his answer is no more useless than your question. You should take Paul R's advice and update your question with something meaningful.

Comment: @Zboson,As I mentioned in reply to PaulR,I will rewrite it here to :I can not write complete code here(cause of agreement issue) but what ever I posted is the dummy code as like my application .This is a part of my code where I am checking the objectness in a frame/image .